# How to apply customized Bootstrap messages errors to devise?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I'm applying Bootstrap3 errors style to all messages in my Rails4 app, here ([source](https://gist.github.com/AhmedNadar/7607251))

```
def bootstrap_class_for flash_type
    { success: "alert-success", error: "alert-error", alert: "alert-warning", notice: "alert-info" }[flash_type] || flash_type.to_s
  end
 
  def flash_messages(opts = {})
    capture do
      flash.each do |msg_type, message|
        concat(content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert #{bootstrap_class_for(msg_type)} fade in") do 
          concat content_tag(:button, 'x', class: "close", data: { dismiss: 'alert' })
          concat message 
        end)
      end
      nil
    end
  end
```

In the same time I'm trying to apply same style to Devise error messages but it does not work.
For example; within [views/devise/registration/new] you see `<%= devise_error_messages! %>` which it shows error messages without style.

How could I apply Bootstrap style (above) to devises error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `devise_error_messages!` helper method

app/helpers/devise_helper.rb

```
module DeviseHelper
 def devise_error_messages!
   return "" if resource.errors.empty?
   messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
   html = <<-HTML
     <div class="alert alert-error alert-block">
       #{messages}
     </div>
    HTML
  html.html_safe
end
```

Where the devise doesn't used any css class so we use `alert-error` class instead you can use your custom class

```
<div class="alert #{boostrap_class_for(:error)} alert-block">
```

Comment: Thanks @nishanthan. I had added this module after I asked the question, but I was not able to figure out how to change the html section and include the predefined CSS. Sometimes obvious solutions are easy and simple if we spotted them or thought of it. 
It was 2am for me and i think my brain was already out of service :)